# R - Sorting rows in a dataframe and returning the second value

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe that looks like this (containing 16060 rows):

```
     CC    A    B    C    D    E    F    G
1     1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2     2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3     3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4     4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5     5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6     6 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
7     7 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
8     8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
9     9 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
10   10 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
11   11 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
12   12 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
13   13 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
14   14 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
15   15 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
16   16 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
17   17 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
18   18 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
19   19 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
20   20 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
21   21 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
22   22 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
23   23 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
24   24 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
25   25 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
26   26 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
27   27 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
28   28 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
29   29 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
30   30 2010 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
31   31 2010 <NA> 2008 2008 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

What I want to do is to sort the values from column 2 to column 8 in each row and return the second lowest value (I don't want NAs to be considered).

When I do it for a single row it works quite good and gives me what I want. Let's take as example row 31:

```
> sort(x[31,-1], decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA)[1,2]
[1] "2008"
```

But when I try to apply this to the whole dataframe it is not working. I tried two different approaches, `sort` and `for` loop, but with no success.

Here is the first try:

```
> x$DA <- apply(x[,-1], 1, 
+               FUN = sort(x[,-1], decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA)[1,2])
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Here is the second:

```
> x$DA <- rep(0, length(x$CC))
> for (i in length(x$CC)) {
+   x$DA[i] <- sort(x[i,2:8], decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA)[1,2]
+   }
```

It gives no errors but nothing happens, as there are no changes in `x$DA` as you can see below:

```
> head(x$DA, 100)
  [1] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [20] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [39] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [58] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [77] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
 [96] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
```

I have no experience with `for` loops so I am surely getting something wrong. I searched for solutions on other threads but nothing seems to match my case. I'm stucked on this for days and a help would be highly appreciated!

You can download the data from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9tii4zm7711v8u/ex.csv?dl=0

Comment: In the first few rows there is only a single non-NA value. What should be returned in those cases?

Comment: you need to do: `apply(x[,-1], 1,  function(myrow) sort(myrow, decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA)[2])`. When you define the function inside the `apply` call, remember you're applying it to a single row, i.e. a `vector`.

Comment: In rows with only NAs, NA schould be returned. The correction of Cath actually works, thanks!